# Disable Build cancel permissions to some users in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, build, permissions, abort

I want to disable "Build cancel" or "Abort" permission in Jenkins.By default if a user is granted Build Permissions he/she have cancel also even if we uncheck the cancel checkbox in Project-Based security matrix.User is able to cancel the jobs.Please help.

Answer (score 2):

So at the moment there is a bit of a discussion about this one. The cancel permission is implied by the build permission, so if you give someone build they also get cancel. There was a PR made to fix this and separate the two permissions, but it seems to not be quite working (or is contentious) - see https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/882 for the PR. I think when that is merged in it will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is now fixed in version 2.120 of Jenkins core. See the release notes here: https://jenkins.io/changelog/#v2.120